# How to upgrade to a later version of Remmina than is in Repository

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, remmina

What's the best-practice way to upgrade to a package that is later than the one that's in the repository?

I continue to experience [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1370014) in Remmina on Ubuntu 14.04. An Arch user informed me that he too was experiencing this before Arch upgraded him to a later version of Remmina (than the one offered in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories).

Brendan Hide said:

> I've had this exact same bug running ArchLinux. Seems to have been
>   fixed in the latest version however. My pacman log shows I updated
>   Remmina on Thursday October 17th from v1.0.0 to v1.1.1.

I've requested, via the bug tracker, for Ubuntu to make this newer package available via the repository, but this has not been granted yet.

So, what's the best practice way to upgrade to a package that is later than the one that's in the repository?

Comment: Already added `trusty-updates` or `backport`, and it's still not there? May have to go to a newer PPA or repo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a PPA for stable versions off Remmina's `master` branch.

Install Remmina 1.1.1 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-master
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Now Ubuntu will keep installing any new versions of Remmina which are put into this repo. If you want to prevent remmina from updating, use the following command:

```
echo remmina hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: After doing this, I can't RDP; I get this error upon trying:
"protocol plugin RDP is not installed"

Comment: I think you may also have to install the freerdp package from the same PPA. Afterwards you may have to do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall remmina`

Comment: I had to install remmina-plugin-rdp to fix this

Comment: [Can't seem to do these steps in 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/604258/remmina-cant-copy-and-paste-between-desktops-in-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Works like a charm on 14.04 and fixes both the file sharing issue AND an ugly screen refresh issue: very nice!

Comment: Can no longer add this repository, had to use snap. :\

Answer (score 3):

The Remmina developers are publishing a [Remmina snap](https://snapcraft.io/remmina). Snaps are supported on all major Linux distros, including Ubuntu 14.04. The advantage of using the snap is that it is always up to date, will automatically update to new releases and is really easy to install the latest version of Remmina.

#### Install Remmina on Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
sudo snap install remmina
```

If you have on old version of Remmina installed via apt you can remove it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get remove remmina remmina-common
```

Comment: Did this and remmina (the command) is no longer available on my PATH. Found a remmina executable in `/snap/remmina/current/usr/bin/`, but it breaks with `libgcrypt.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So, problems installing using apt-get, snap broken. It amazes me that this falls apart so badly. :\

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up. I tried this recently and it does upgrade remmina and RDP works great. However, it replaces `libfreerdp1` with a different version that causes `vlc` to be removed due to a missing dependency.

I ended up forcing `vlc` to install by using `apt-get download` to get all of the deb packages except the `libfreerdp1` for `vlc` and then performed a `dpkg --force-depends` to get it to install. It seems to work so far. YMMV